# .htaccess file not working in codeigniter after change the version to 2.1.1

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, version

I want to redirect the URl from

http://www.mydomain.com/b2b/testarab

To

http://www.mydomain.com/b2b/index.php/business/show/testarab

I've also set

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

My .htaccess files is

```
RewriteEngine on
php_value max_file_uploads 30
RewriteBase /b2b
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \s
RewriteRule  ^(home.*|buyers.*|sellers.*|companies.*|mall.*|category.*|product_details.*|contact_now.*|join.*|login.*|myprofile.*|dashboard.*|buy_sell_items.*|trade.*|media.*|myadvertise.*|mycontacts.*|myemail.*|myhotel.*|mymedia.*|payment.*|tradeshows.*|tradeshow_details.*|search_tradeshows.*|business.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9._-\s]+)$ index.php/business/show/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

In this file first RewriteRule is working..
the second one is not working..

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Set the variable empty as below.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

try to replace following variable with these parameters ('AUTO', 'PATH_INFO', 'QUERY_STRING', 'REQUEST_URI', and 'ORIG_PATH_INFO') one by one

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed Samy...
Thanks now working good i put PATH_NFO.. Please tell me it ll affect the other pages.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: it shouldnt affect any pages